# cucumber runtimeOptions error when trying to run cucumber feature file

Tags: cucumber

see this error when trying to execute a feature file.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.thucydides.core.steps.StepEventBus.isBaseStepListenerRegistered()Z

Error when trying to run cucumber class java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.formatter(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lcucumber/api/formatter/Formatter;
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IntelliJ and Cucumber v2.x, please upgrade IntelliJ and try uninstalling/installing the Jetbrains Cucumber-for-Java plugin.

The Cucumber event model was upgraded with Cucumber v2.x and the plugin was recently upgraded to deal with that.

Otherwise, try removing the Formatter from your Run Configuration (generated by IntelliJ)